# What are the meaning of the extra values I'm getting from bid_info

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

For one of my ads, I'm getting the following bid_info:

```
"bid_type": 6,
"bid_info": {
   "1": 24, 
   "37": 0, 
   "38": 27, 
   "44": 26, 
   "45": 0, 
   "46": 0, 
   "48": 0, 
   "55": 23
}
```

I came to understand that "37" was also "impressions" (not "Social Impressions"?), but what do the values 45, 46 and 48 map to? It seems I only have that for bid_type 6 (RELATIVE_OCPM), is that normal?

Yes I know about the October 2nd breaking changes that is why I'm inquiring about this field, I even tried to find past information using the waybackmachine to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> 1  => 'clicks',
> 37 => 'impressions',
> 38 => 'social',
> 44 => 'reach', 
> 55 => 'actions'
> ```

All I can figure out at this point